# why null values are not honored by unique constraint, but honored by SELECT distinct query in POSTGRES?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, distinct, unique-constraint

I am working with postgres. I have created a sample table whose schema looks like given below :-

```
postgres=# \d temp;
                         Table "public.temp"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('temp_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | text    |
Indexes:
    "temp_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "temp_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
```

It's allowing me to insert null values multiple times.

```
postgres=# select * from temp;
 id | name
----+------
  1 |
(1 row)

postgres=# insert into temp
(name)
values
(null);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from temp;
 id | name
----+------
  1 |
  2 |
(2 rows)
```

I know that postgres doesn't consider null values for unique constraint, as per sql standard, but when I try distinct with select query, it honors null values.

```
postgres=# select distinct name from temp;
 name
------

(1 row)
```

So, I am not clear about why two null values are different in context of unique constraint in insert operation, but same in case of distinct select operation.

Comment: That is simply how SQL is defined.  The handling of `NULL` is not always consistent (note that `group by` works the same way that `distinct` does).

Comment: POSTGRES doesn't follow the ANSI standard for unique constraints, as you noted in your question. You can work around this, but basically you are working around something that is fundamentally broken in this RDBMS.

Comment: @RichardHansell - Eh? - per the ANSI 92 spec, but fairly certain it's not changed - "A unique constraint is satisfied if and only if no two rows in
         a table have the same **non-null values** in the unique columns". It's SQL Server that's non-compliant by only allowing a single `null` value.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I meant to type "SQL standard", not "ANSI standard". My take on this is that the ANSI standard doesn't really work, as it doesn't cover what to do with NULL values, so it's really open to interpretation, and the way POSTGRES does this often causes issues. If you go back to Codd's original design for relational databases then we probably aren't handling NULLs correctly in any case? I guess you could argue that the ANSI standard does cover NULLs, but I think it's at least unclear?

Comment: What is this "SQL standard"? Personally, I only know of ANSI